# Black spots near the roots of my Areca Plant and leaves turning grey and brown!

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, leaves, diseases

I have had this areca plant for about 8 months. Lately I have been noticing a lot of brown and grey leaves and even whole stems. I cut off those leaves and removed the stems from the root which were completely dead. It's been two days since I did that and I am starting to spot new leaves getting greyish again:
[image]

On top of that, there seems to be a white cast in some of the leaves: [image]

There are also some brownish leave ends in most of the leaves of the plant. Also, near the root the plant presents these spots: [image]

These spots are also in higher parts of the stem. They do not look like bugs but I am unsure of what is causing this..

Can anyone help me? Thank you :)